# I can't integrate a Web Template purchased into Meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, html, angular-meteor

thanks for read

I have a problem, I hope some orientation because always I worked only with bootstrap. Never with css, js, or templates. But this case is diferent.

I bought a template in wrapbootstrap.com
As you know, this templates coming with a big set number files like a js, img, fonts, and of course html. Of course not always this packages are in NPM, and that is all a problem, because if only one missing file, for some reason many components dont work as well like I expect. So, the solution is, although no elegant but efective, is copy and paste these files that I bought in a correct directory in meteor.

I need integrate this template into meteor, I find in web tha `Meteor.startup()` help. This code help a little to solve, but no solve the problem.

I have the next issue:
Sometimes the template is good, works fine and very well, sometimes is very, very bad and infinite erros.
Next a img

[image: sometimes good, sometimes bad]

As you can see: Window on right is perfect, everithings well. The window on left is bad, and with errors. **Why?** sometimes good, sometimes bad

next my file structure:

[image: My file structure]

my file **client/main.js** has the next lines:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';

import {name as Inicio} from '../imports/ui/components/views/inicio/inicio';

class Main {} // EMPYT

Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/jquery.superslides.min.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/owl.carousel.min.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/imagesloaded.pkgd.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/isotope.pkgd.min.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/packery-mode.pkgd.min.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/appear.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/wow.min.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/jqBootstrapValidation.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/jquery.fitvids.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/smoothscroll.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/gmaps.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/contact.js', function () {});});
Meteor.startup(function () {$.getScript('js/custom.js', function () {});});

const name = 'main';

export default angular.module('myApp', [
    angularMeteor,
    uiRouter,
    Inicio
])
    .config(config);

function config($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    'ngInject';
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/inicio');

}
```

My questions:

- **Is a good way to import files like this?**
- **Iam doing something wrong?**
- **Exist other way?**

Please need help, due I don't understand the File Structure documentation. 
I need a example.
Thanks for your time and read

Aditional notes:

- My file `client/main.less` is empyt, no conflict with it
- `/lib` directory is empyt
- Am working with Angular, AngularMeteor, UiRoute
- For now, all html is in `imports\ui\components\views\inicio\inicio.html`
- Imposible rename the js files with a number before the name, like _1appear.js, the template don't works that way
- The load order is like the template indicates, like as my `client/main.js` has.
- If I put my js files into a `client/compatibility` appear more errors.
- I new in Meteor but not in Tempaltes Web, I integrated more templates in fullstack with yeoman and grunt, no problems, but in meteor is very dificult.

Comment: `getScript()` is async; that won't work.  You should wrap those files in modules.

Comment: @ SLaks Hello friend. So, when you advice me wrap those files in modules, how I made this? for example: my file public/js/custom.js start in line 1 with (function ($) { code.. code..  how I shold wrap into a module? with angular-meteor?

Comment: With ES6 modules (`import` and `export`), exactly like you already did in main.js.

Comment: @SLaks Your advice It works almost entirely. Only have a issue with 2 files from isotope (isotope.pkgd.min.js and packery-mode.pkgd.min.js)  When I import that files the console send me the error: Uncaught Error: No layout mode: packery. The good news is that 'Isotope Library' is aviable in NPM and Admosphere, but no solve the problem, almost entirely. This is why I like copy and paste .js original files in my proyect. Thank you very much, we are near to solve the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to port those files to use modules (or find already-wrapped versions on npm), so that they can be bundled up in the correct order with the rest of your JS code.

Comment: Man, Thank you very much for your atention, But I can't understand you. Let me explain. I import my .js files like this: import '../public/js/custom.js'; .......... This files load very good, except my new issue with Isotope. You spoke about 'bundled up' what do you mean 'bundled up'?  Thank you.